# is it possible to install Adobe Reader X or X1 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: adobe, adobe-reader

If it is, can you please provide the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not native and we probably never will have an Ubuntu version for Adobe Reader. Adobe dropped support for Linux somewhere in 2013. [9.5.5](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb) is still available on their website but 10 and 11 are nowhere to be found.

---

You can try to install 11 with Wine but I doubt it is worth your time since neither 10 nor 11 have a good rating.

- [Status on wineHQ for AR10](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22577):  Garbage
- [Status on AR11](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093): Bronze. See "Important Note on How to Install and run Adobe Reader 11.x" below the status. Someone got it working but it will be a lot of trial and error. Plus you probably need a fair amount of knowledge on how Wine works.

---

If you have to have it I would install a Windows in a VirtualBox and install/use it from there.

Comment: Thanks,is their any other similar pdf file reader like Adobe(x or X1) which provides commenting or highlighting features?

Comment: Not that I know of ... there is a reason why Adobe only supports Windows+Mac... paying for it gets you "better" software. And we tend to not want to pay for software ;)